# Threads and synchronisation using pipe in c++

Tags: c++, named-pipes, thread-synchronization

I have two threads. one thread generate a number and the other squares the number generated. I need to synchronise this action using pipes or semaphore or message queues . Help me with this problem

Comment: Hi and welcome. this is not the right way to ask a question. did you google your problem? did you try to program something yourself?it'll be difficult to find someone to just give you ready code to solve your problem. read this http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ good luck

Comment: If you have threads in the very same process, you can use condition variables if they are available on your system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong way to go. Generating  an extra thread and synchronizing the two threads would require more CPU power than just squaring the number in the generator thread.

Implementing a pipeline is effective only when each step requires enough computational power to justify the extra thread.

As for your questions, I suggest you should read about the [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern. There are many implementations on the wild.